# Running queries against a list of lists in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, matching

I'm stuck in the middle of my project. I have a list of lists like:

```
'((a for apple) (b is book) (c in cat) (ronn live in NY))
```

Now I want to make a query in the form of a list and have it display the correct entry in my list of lists. For example, if I input `'(a for what)` or `'(what in cat)` it will display `(a for apple)` or `(c in cat)`. If I input `'(ronn live in where)` it will show `(ronn live in NY)`.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: This is almost exactly an association list (aka alist), but the format is enough different to be really hard to implement. If it doesn't have to be *exactly* like that, check out `assoc`.

Comment: thanks rysdam this was realy helpful.. but I need the full information like (a for apple) in answer. still need help..

Answer (score 0):

How about running a `filter` routine across the list, and using a lambda object initialized with your query information that will then be applied to the list until it finds a match.

So for instance, you would have a lamda that would look something like

```
(define (filter-object query)
    (define (query-function list-input)
        ;;do something here for query function that will take the initialized
        ;;query and match it against the list-input to see if there's a match
        ;;it should return #t or #f
    )

    ;;the return of the filter-object is the query function
    query_function) 

;;my-filter-function is initialized with a specific query
(define my-filter-function (filter-object '(a for what)))
```

Now with the `filter-object` initialized, run a filter across your list

```
(define (filter filter-function list-of-lists)
    (cond ((eq? list-of-lists '()) '())
          ((filter-function (car list-of-lists))
           (cons (car list-of-lists)
              (filter filter-function (cdr list-of-lists)))
          (else (filter filter-function (cdr list-of-lists))))

(filter my-filter-function my-list)
```

This should return a one-element list of the matches (providing you aren't placing more than one copy in your list set.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: Great! Really happy to help out :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, Video Lectures by Hal Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/)

Lecture 4a, Pattern Matching and Rule-based Substitution